# Failing to communicate between two Docker containers via Rest API using Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, rest

I have two Java Spring Boot applications:
On port 8080:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class LogonPageApplication {
    private static final String PROCESS_STRING_URL = "http://localhost:8081/processString";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LogonPageApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/send")
    public String test() {

        String responseBody = "";
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            String requestBody = "{testttgfvrdf}";
            HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);

            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(PROCESS_STRING_URL, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);

            responseBody = response.getBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }

        return "Main Page\n" + "Response from /processString: " + responseBody;
    }

}
```

On port 8081:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class AcceptMessageApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AcceptMessageApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostMapping("/processString")
    public String processString(@RequestBody String inputString) {
        return "Processed string: " + inputString;
    }

}
```

I have two Dockerfiles:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/AcceptMessage-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/AcceptMessage-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "AcceptMessage-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

With filenames beeing the only differences

And a docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  appacc:
    build:
      context: AcceptMessage
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    networks:
      - my-network
  applog:
    build:
      context: LogonPage
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:

# docker-compose build
# docker-compose up
```

This app works as intended when I run it from a console and so does the endpoint when sending a requst via Postman, however I cannot get them to exchange message having dockerized it whenever I enter http://localhost:8080/send resulting in:

**I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8081/processString": Connection refused.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Localhost inside a container is not the same as localhost outside of a container. Hence you cannot reference the other container like this.

Luckily since you are using `docker-compose` in the way that you are,you can just directly connect to it under `appacc` so you need to adjust this in the first code bit:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class LogonPageApplication {
    private static final String PROCESS_STRING_URL = "http://appacc:8080/processString";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LogonPageApplication.class, args);
    }
```

You are connecting directly to the container on the container port. Hence the port is `8080` not `8081` as that would be what you're mapping to on the host port. Theoretically you could drop that mapping from the docker-compose unless you still want to reach the containers from the host as well.

Small note: you don't need to manually create a network unless you explicitly want to reference it since the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) states the following

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

Comment: Welp it worked after setting PROCESS_STRING_URL to **"http://appacc:8080/processString"**, which leaves me very confused

Comment: that's my bad. copy paste is evil. made a small note that explains the why. Hope that leaves you a little less puzzled?

Comment: Yes it does. Last question - if I created two endpoints on dfiferent services accepting the same type of data would this give me an error or only one of them will be picked when making request?

Comment: You would still connect to them independently, so nothing should happen.
for example you could have `mysql1` and `mysql2` and `mysql3`. Each of them would still listen on 3306 but there's nothing bad here, you'd connect to each of them independently as `mysql1:3306` for example from inside a given application. You just can't expose the same port to the host multiple times, because that port only exists once on the host, obviously. in the example you couldn't have a mapping of `3306:3306` for all of the mysql instances

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand `8081:8080` means to map your local machines port 8081 to your container's port 8080. And then from other container you are trying to access `localhost:8081` which means it is trying to reach the 2nd container's network, not your local/host machine's network. A container cannot access your machine's network through localhost.

There are 2 ways for this

1. **Not the best way**: use `host.docker.internal:8081` which means to use the host network.
2. **The best approach** As both containers are already on same network so use the other container's name and container's port, so in your case `appacc:8080` so now you wont need 8081 as you are directly calling the container, so thats why 8080