# Dockerized Liquibase cannot connect to Dockerized Scylladb, getting "DatabaseException: Connection could not be created"

Tags: docker, cassandra, liquibase, scylla, cassandra-jdbc-driver

I'm working with liquibase migration tool, it is working fine through terminal (update the table in scylla db).

Now I want to dockerize it, for this I do the following steps:

1. Create liquibase.properties file:

   changeLogFile: changelog.sql

   url: jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9041/mykeyspace

   driver: com.simba.cassandra.jdbc42.Driver

   defaultSchemaName: mykeyspace

My scylladb container is running at port 9041 with keyspace 'mykeyspace'

2. Create changelog.sql file:

   ```
    --liquibase formatted sql

    --changeset liquibase:1
    CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS studentkeyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': 3};

    --changeset liquibase:2
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS studentkeyspace.studentData (name text, Id text PRIMARY KEY, email text)
   ```
3. Create docker compose file:

version: '3'

```
services:
  liquibase:
    image: liquibase/liquibase:4.1.1
    container_name: liquibasecontainer
    volumes:
      - ./changelogs:/liquibase/changelogs
      - ./liquibase.properties:/liquibase/liquibase.properties
      - /home/asif/Liquibase/liquibase-4.1.1/lib:/liquibase/lib
    command: ["--defaultsFile=/liquibase/liquibase.properties", "update"]
```

When I run command 'docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up'
It generate an error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9041/mykeyspace with driver com.simba.cassandra.jdbc42.Driver.  [Simba][CassandraJDBCDriver](500150) Error setting/closing connection: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9041 (com.simba.cassandra.shaded.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9041] Cannot connect)).
liquibasecontainer | For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
liquibasecontainer exited with code 255
```

How can I remove this error ?

Comment: So to clarify, you have a scyllaDB container, and now you are adding another container that has the liquibase in it and from the syntax, I'm assuming you're using docker compose?

Comment: Yes Rick Rackow You are right .
ScyllaDB container is running and now I'm trying to run another container having liquibase using Docker-compose

Comment: ok then you can't connect to localhost. --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/76882431/6336357

Comment: Thanks for your precious time.
I Tried to connect it using IP:Port but nothing happened  such as 

url: jdbc:cassandra://172:19:02:9041/mykeyspace

url: jdbc:cassandra://scylla-node:9041/mykeyspace

but still getting same connection error.

Comment: isn't the default port for scylla 9042? how did you specify a different port?

Comment: While creating scyllaDB container I specified the port, such as 
 `  scylla-node1:
    container_name: scylla-node1
    image: scylladb/scylla:4.5.0
    ports:
      - 9041:9042`

(here is some part of docker-compose where i set the port 9041)

Comment: yeah no. that is the port you're mapping to on the host. I explained that in the answer i linked right under the code snippet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254942/discussion-between-asif-and-rick-rackow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to connect two containers, not two services on the host. If you use `localhost` in a container it is referring to inside the container. Inside your `liquibase` container nothing is listening on port 9041.

The right way to do this is (when using docker-compose), by referencing the container that runs scylla directly. In your case that is `scylla node`.

Now it is also important to note, that when doing that, you need to use the port that scylla is listening on, not the port that you expose to the host. For Scylla DB that is port 9042 as you can read [in the documentation](https://opensource.docs.scylladb.com/stable/operating-scylla/admin.html#networking).

Your adjusted `properties` part would look like this:

```
url: jdbc:cassandra://scylla-node:9042/mykeyspace
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, the driver threw a `TransportException` because there is no connectivity to `localhost` in the Scylla container, therefore "Cannot connect":

```
... com.simba.cassandra.shaded.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: \
      [localhost/127.0.0.1:9041] Cannot connect ...
```

By definition, `localhost` is *local* to the host so it can only be accessed withIN that operating system instance (OSI).

To access services from "outside" the container, you need to expose (publish) the port to the outside world using the `--publish` (or `-p`) flag.

Once you've exposed the CQL port, you will need configure the JDBC URL with with the Scylla container's hostname or IP that is accessible/reachable/routable from the Liquibase container. For details, see [Docker Networking overview](https://docs.docker.com/network/).

As a side note, the Simba JDBC driver for Apache Cassandra is proprietary software (not open-source) so its use is subject to terms and conditions.

Under [the license terms](https://www.datastax.com/legal/simba-odbcjdbc-driver-license-terms), the Simba JDBC driver can only be used with (1) DataStax software and services such as DataStax Enterprise or (2) Apache Cassandra. It is otherwise a breach of license to use the driver to connect to other software or services including variants which are Cassandra-compatible. Cheers!