# How to connect multiple microservices to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run two microservices each service is SpringBoot + Mongodb + Gradle on docker-compose container, named Customer and Stock, Customer runs fine and these are the setups for it;

Customer microservice

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=store_stock
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
server.port=5001
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 5001:5001
  contextPath: /customer

spring:
  application:
    name: Customer-Service
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://mongodb:27017/store_stock
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  customer:
    build: .
    container_name: customer-service
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z mongodb 27017
      interval: 5s
    container_name: mongodb-customer
    ports:
      - 27019:27017
```

But the Stock one gives out the error stated below.
Stock microservice

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=store_stock
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
server.port=5000
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 5000:5000
  contextPath: /stock

spring:
  application:
    name: Stock-Service
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://mongodb:27017/store_stock
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  stock-service:
    build: .
    container_name: stock-service
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z mongodb 27017
      interval: 5s
    container_name: mongodb-stock
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Exception

```
INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
 at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$OpenChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:514) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
 at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$OpenChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:487) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.100.Final.jar!/:4.1.100.Final]
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]
 Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:27017
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: In your second configuration, you're connecting to port 27020, but you need the standard MongoDB port 27017 (the same as your first configuration).

Comment: If I use the same port I get `0.0.0.0:27017: bind: address already in use`

Comment: You're confusing local port (ie inside the container) with host port.  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76882431/6336357

Comment: I have tried as suggested but still no success unfortunately.